# How can I make custom selector with input on clicking it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

Please,help me to make one element!
I have an element with custom selector. When you click on an arrow, you open selector. When you precisely click on an element you open an input. The problem is that the input should recieve a focus immediately after it is open, not after second click. I tried to make it with "$refs", but it didn't work. Now I have an idea to make a function that will create this input and maybe than it will receive a focus.

````
  <div class="mainBuySelector">
    <div :style="{width: mainWidth, height: mainHeight}" class="selectorUp">
      <div @click="openSelector = !openSelector" class="selectorArrow"/>
      <div @click="makeFocusOnInput" class="activeOption thin">
        <div class="thin" v-if="setChangeValue">{{setChangeValue}}</div>
        <div class="thin" v-else-if="defaultValue">{{defaultValueStr}}</div>
        <div v-else>{{data.items[selected].index}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <portal to="destinationAdd">
      <div v-if="openSelector" class="mainOpenSelector"> 
        <div class="positioningWrap">
        <div v-if="openSelector" :style="optionStyle" class="selectorOptions">
          <div class="innerSelectorWrap" v-for="(el, key) in data.items" :key="key">
            <div @click="select(key)" class="smallText selectorBuyItem">{{el.index}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div @click="hide()" class="closeSelContainer" />
      </div>
    </portal>
    <div 
      :style="{top: alignDataInput.top, left: alignDataInput.left, bottom: alignDataInput.bottom, right:alignDataInput.right, width: inputWidth}" 
      class="inputWrapBuy"
      v-show="selectorInput"
    >
      <div >
        <input 
          ref="myInputs"
          @input="sendInput()"
          :style="{width: inputInnerWidth}"
          :type='type'
          v-model="selInput"
          :placeholder="defaultPlaceholder"
          class="inputBuy thin" />
      </div>
      <div @click="closeInput()" class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  GET_BUYING_INF
} from '@/store/rest/action-types'
import { Socketervice } from '@/api/service'
export default {
  props: {
    mainWidth: String,
    mainHeight: String,
    width: String,
    height: String,
    inputWidth: String,
    objectOptionChoice: Number,
    alignData: Object,
    alignDataInput: Object,
    data: Object,
    alignDataAdd: Object,
    inputInnerWidth: String,
    defaultPlaceholder: String,
    defaultValueStr: String,
    type: String,
    setValue: String
  },
  data () {
    return {
      emails: [],
      selected: 0,
      optionStyle: Object.assign(this.alignData, {width: this.width, height: this.height}),
      openSelector: false,
      selectorInput: false,
      defaultValue: true,
      selInput: '',
      setChangeValue: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    makeFocusOnInput () {
      // this.$nextTick(() => {
      //   const lastIdx = 0;
      //   console.log(this.$refs)
      //   this.$refs.myInputs[lastIdx].focus();
        
      // })
      // this.$refs["myInputs"].open = true;
      // this.$refs["myInputs"].focus()
      // this.selectorInput = true


      
    },
    select (key) {
      this.openSelector = false
      this.defaultValue = false
      this.selected = key
      const val = this.data.items[this.selected].param
      Socketervice.send({
        service: 'booking_price',
        data: {
          pc: this.computerInfo.id,
          date_start: this.$moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
          date_end: this.$moment(new Date(Date.now() + val * (60 * 60 * 1000))).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
          type: 1
        }
      })
    },
    sendInput () {
      let obj = new Object()
      if (this.type === 'time') {
        obj.avaliableTime = this.selInput
      }
      else if (this.type === 'customTime') {
        obj.customTime = this.selInput
      }
      else if (this.type === 'price') {
        obj.price = this.selInput
      }
      console.log(obj)
      this.$store.dispatch(GET_BUYING_INF)
    },
    closeInput () {
      this.selectorInput = false
      this.openSelector = true
    },
    hide () {
      this.openSelector = false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    setValue: function (val) {
      if (val) {
        this.setChangeValue = val
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computerInfo () {
      return this.$store.state.computerInfo
    },
    buyInfInput () {
      return this.$store.state.buyingInf
    }
  }
}

</script>```
````

Comment: Did you try this `document.getElementById("{inputElementId}").focus();`?

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add

```
makeFocusOnInput () {
      this.selectorInput = true
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.myInputs.focus()
      })
    }
```